# Proving $\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{T_R} f(z)dz=i A\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

If $f(z)$ is continuous in $\vert z \vert\ge R_0$, $0\le arg(z)\le \alpha,  (0\lt \alpha\le 2\pi)$ and the limit $ \lim_{z\to \infty} zf(z)=A$ exist, then $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{T_R} f(z)dz=i A\alpha$$ where $T_R$ is the arc of the circumference $\vert z\vert=R$ which is in $\vert z \vert\ge R_0$ and traversed in the positive direction with respect to the origin of coordinates.

I'm trying to make the proof but it's not easy for me.

Practically I have two circumferences, one of radio $R_0$ and the other one (which is bigger) of radio $R$, and as R goes to $\infty$,$\int_{T_R} f(z)dz$ must be equal to $i \alpha z f(z)$, in which $z$ goes to $\infty$ too.

But I don't know how to use the hypothesis of continuity and also how to continue the proof.

Any hint/help would be great.

Comment: Estimate $$\int_{T_R} f(z) - \frac{A}{z}\,dz.$$

Comment: hmm will I get something like this $\int_{T_R} f(z)dz-\int_{T_R} \frac{A}{z}dz$ and the first integral can be expressed like $\int_0^\alpha f(T_R(t)) T_R'(t)dt$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer what can I do next?

Comment: Do you know the standard estimate (also known as ML estimate)?

Comment: no, what is it?

Comment: $$\Biggl\lvert\int_{\gamma} g(z)\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant L(\gamma)\cdot \max \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in \operatorname{Trace} \gamma\}$$

Comment: and how do I use it for the proof of the theorem? @DanielFischer

Comment: $$\Biggl\lvert \int_{T_R} f(z) - \frac{A}{z}\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant R\alpha\cdot \max \: \biggl\{ \frac{\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert} : z \in T_R\biggr\}$$

Comment: and where should I introduce the $\epsilon$ inequality?. Because I think that's the goal, to have something like this: $\vert \int_{T_R} f(z)dz-iA\alpha\vert<\epsilon$ @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

$$iA\alpha = \int_{T_R} \frac{A}{z}\,dz.\tag{1}$$

Or if one doesn't know it, one can easily verify it, but without seeing $(1)$, a proof of the proposition is hard to find. To verify $(1)$, parametrise $T_R$ by $\gamma \colon [0,\alpha] \to \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(t) = R\cdot e^{it}$. Then

$$\int_{T_R} \frac{A}{z}\,dz = \int_0^{\alpha} \frac{A}{\gamma(t)}\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt = \int_0^{\alpha} \frac{A}{R e^{it}}\cdot R ie^{it}\,dt = iA\int_0^{\alpha}dt = iA\alpha$$

is a straightforward calculation.

Thus we can rewrite the assertion to be proved as

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \Biggl\lvert \int_{T_R} f(z) - \frac{A}{z}\,dz\Biggr\rvert = 0.\tag{2}$$

By the form of the given assumption, it is not hard to guess that it is helpful to rewrite the integrand in $(2)$ as $\dfrac{zf(z) - A}{z}$. By the assumption $\lim\limits_{z\to \infty} zf(z) = A$, for every $\eta > 0$ there is an $R(\eta)$ such that $\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert \leqslant \eta$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant R(\eta)$. Hence, for $R \geqslant R(\eta)$ we have

$$\Biggl\lvert \int_{T_R} \frac{zf(z)-A}{z}\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant L(T_R)\cdot \max \biggl\{ \frac{\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert} : z \in T_R\biggr\} \leqslant L(T_R)\cdot \frac{\eta}{R} = \alpha R\cdot \frac{\eta}{R} = \alpha\eta$$

by the standard estimate (ML inequality). Thus, choosing $\eta = \varepsilon/\alpha$ for a given $\varepsilon > 0$, we see that for $R \geqslant R(\varepsilon/\alpha)$ we have

$$\Biggl\lvert \int_{T_R} f(z)\,dz - iA\alpha\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon,$$

and $(2)$ is proven.

Comment: hmm where do you use the continuity of $f(z)$ ?

Comment: Why $\max \biggl\{ \frac{\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert} : z \in T_R\biggr\}  \leqslant  \frac{\eta}{R} $ ?

Comment: The continuity of $f$ is not really important for this. It's a convenient way to ensure that $\int_{T_R} f(z)\,dz$ is defined for all $R > R_0$, but other than that, we don't need it. The limit $zf(z) \to A$ is the important part. But since one applies the result only (or almost only, to leave me a bit of wiggle room) to continuous functions, there's no need to state the weaker but more wordy hypothesis that suffices for the result.

Comment: For $R \geqslant R(\eta)$, we have $\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert \leqslant \eta$ on $T_R$, by definition of $R(\eta)$. On $T_R$, we also have $\lvert z\rvert = R$, hence $\dfrac{\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert} = \dfrac{\lvert zf(z) - A\rvert}{R} \leqslant \dfrac{\eta}{R}$ on $T_R$.